# Regular expression for only allowing alphanumeric, dashes, underscores

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to allow only `A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, _`

I'm using the following expression which is working:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/i', $_POST['sign_up_username'])
```

Is this the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please point out any problems or challenges you are facing with this.

Comment: @AKS Basically will my regex only allow A-Z both upper and lowercase, numbers, dashes, and underscores. I just started working with regex a few days ago so I'm still very uncertain of how to do stuff with them.

Comment: Why would one want to limit user account names in that a narrow manner?

Comment: Not account names, usernames. I don't want my users to have names like "@Bob&Joe*youtube"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex is incorrect. Move `-` in last or beginning or escape it in character class because `-` have special meaning inside character class. It denotes `range` within character class. You can use

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

Also

```
\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

So, you can use

```
^[\w-]+$
```

Also, there is no need of `i` modifier and finally yes it will allow only ***A-Z both upper and lowercase, numbers, dashes, and underscores***

This will suffice in PHP

```
preg_match('/^[\w-]+$/', $_POST['sign_up_username'])
```

Comment: Could you give me an example in terms of `preg_match`? I'm still very uncertain about the slashes at the end and beginning.

Comment: @Coilerz updated..you can use if condition with `preg_match`.`/` is just for denoting what exists between `/../` to be treated as regex

Answer (score -1):

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/i', $str) == 1)

{

```
// string only contain the a to z , A to Z, 0 to 9,  -_
```

echo "yes";

}

else

{

echo " no";

}